# Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::url() cannot be called statically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm using Laravel 9 and I want to redirect user to same page url, so I tried this:

```
if(!$status){
    alert()->error('Wrong code!');
    return redirect(Request::url());
}
```

And I have included as well the `Request` but don't know why get this error:

**Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::url() cannot be called statically**

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

Or

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function yourMethod(Request $request) # inject $request here
{
    return redirect($request->url());
}
```

Comment: What does `->withInput();` do

Comment: Return will all your input data. Example form user inputs. You can use `old()` to capture. google it